# Widget stuck on "Unable to load a hot question, check your internet connection"

Tags: bug, android-app, android-app-widgets

The hot questions widget seems unable to load questions. This has been going on for the last one month, I have tried clearing app data, removing and reinstalling the app, removing and recreating the widget but all to no avail.

- App Version: 1.0.92
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: ONE A2003
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (31)

Comment: They are busy with a new app these days, so pretty sure they won't bother to fix this.